# Angular 2 Component in a component not displaying?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, nativescript

I am building a mobile app using Angular 2 and Nativescript. My Current setup has my `HomeComponent`, which contains a `DockComponent`. The `DockComponent` renders and works fine, however, I now want to abstract out each of the four buttons in the dock, so I have created a `LoginComponent` and tried to include that in my DockComponent, but it isn't displaying, see below - what have I done wrong?

I thought that by referencing the components selector and importing the component and adding it to the providers array of the parent component, that it would work?

#### Dock.Component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Login} from "../Login/login.component";

@Component({
    selector: "dock",
    templateUrl: `Components/Dock/dock.html`,
    styleUrls: ["Components/Dock/dock.css"],
    providers: [Login]
})

export class Dock implements OnInit {

}
```

#### Login.Component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "login",
    templateUrl: `Components/Dock/Login/login.html`,
    styleUrls: ["Components/Dock/Login/login.css"],
    providers: []
})

export class Login implements OnInit {

    page: Page;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.page = <Page>topmost().currentPage;
    }
}
```

#### Dock.html:

```
<FAB row="8" col="0" icon="res://help" class="fab-button help" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" (tap)="fabTap()"></FAB>
<FAB row="8" col="1" class="fab-button bluetooth" icon="res://bluetoothg" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" (tap)="fabTap()"></FAB>
<login></login>
<FAB row="8" col="3" icon="res://plus" class="fab-button" id="add" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" (tap)="bluetoothAdd()"></FAB>
<ActivityIndicator row="8" col="3" busy="{{ isScanning }}" id="ActivityIndicator"></ActivityIndicator>
```

#### login.html:

(this is coped and pasted from where `<login></login>` now is in the dock.html file - where it worked fine)

```
<FAB row="8" col="2" icon="res://facebook" class="fab-button" id="facebook" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" (tap)="login('Facebook')"></FAB>
<FAB row="8" col="2" icon="res://google" class="fab-button" id="google" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" (tap)="login('Google')"></FAB>
<FAB row="8" col="2" icon="res://amazon" class="fab-button" id="amazon" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" (tap)="login('amazon')"></FAB>
<FAB row="8" col="2" icon="res://key" class="fab-button login" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" (tap)="socialClick()"></FAB>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing:

```
providers: [Login]
```

To:

```
directives: [Login]
```

`providers` does not appear to be valid. To allow a template to have access to a sub-component, you need to define it as a `directive`. Note this is an array, so multiple components can be defined here. [More details](http://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html)